# XCode project compiling

Tags: xcode

I get the chromium source and I am able to compile it fine under MaxOS X. 
My question is why every time I power off my laptop and then re-open my XCode project and click 'Build and Go (Debug)', XCode recompiles EVERYTHING (even I have not modified any file).

Is there any way to config to compile when needed?

Thank you for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... It's hard to say what the issue here is. I haven't noticed this problem, XCode only compiles things that I have changed in chromium, most of the time anyway. You might try doing just "Build" on the all project (I'm assuming you are building the chrome project, since all doesn't have the option to "Build and Go"). If that doesn't solve your problem, you should stop by the chromium irc channel and ask (chromium on irc.freenode.net). They can probably help you more there.